# FFMPEG: How to move the video without stretching it?

Tags: scroll, ffmpeg, crop

Please, I need help with the following ...

I want to move a video (portrait type), but without stretching it ...
To create a 16: 9 video, with FFMPEG ...
I have the following example ...

`ffmpeg -i video.mpg -filter:v "crop=in_w-100:in_h-100:0:(in_h-out_h)/2 +((in_h-out_h)/2)*sin(t)" -y out.mp4`

[image: Example conceptual image]

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I do not know what I was thinking ...
The answer was simple, indicate the HxW of the output video ...

`ffmpeg -i video.mpg -filter:v "crop=1280:720:0:(in_h-out_h)/2 +((in_h-out_h)/2)*sin(t)" -y out.mp4`

But: **How do I resize the background video, if I want to create a 640x360 video?**

I tried to include "scale" and do some tests, but I still can NOT make the background video, also scale to 640x360.
`ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -filter:v "crop=640:360:0:(in_h-out_h)/2 +((in_h-out_h)/2)*sin(t),scale=640:360" out.mp4`.

Video output: https://youtu.be/TCOLbbereQU

Comment: Add a scale filter afterwards, `scale=640:360`

Comment: Hi @Gyan,
Exactly how do I set the scale? Thanks!